string format to insert into tkinter combobox
The python console prints the string correctly {"/dev/ttyS4","/dev/ttyS0","/dev/ttyACM0" } for inserting into the combobox selection but when run the combobox prints only one charecter instead of each selection as above
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter

import serial.tools.list_ports

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
#root = Tk()
root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.title('Combo Box Ports')
root.geometry('700x450')

get_sel_val = ''
#print(type(get_sel_val))

ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
for p in ports:
#    print(p.device)
#print(len(ports), 'ports found')    
    if (p.device) != (''):
        get_sel_val = get_sel_val + '"' + (p.device) + '",'
        #print(p)
        #print(p.device)
        #print (type(p.device))
print(get_sel_val)
          
my_combo = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(root, values = get_sel_val)
my_combo.pack(pady=20)    

....
I was expecting tkinter combobox selectios to be
    /dev/ttyS4
    /dev/ttyS0
    /dev/ttyACM0
not --> / d / e v 


Thanks Toyota but I put 4 spaces on each line before pasting each line of code. How do I find instructions on how to post so you won't be disturbed? Help was of no help to me.

Is a def statement with a .config or lambda statement required required to place the new values in the drop-down of the combo box?

You need to pass an iterable (eg: list, tuple) as the value for values, but you're passing a string. Since Tkinter will iterate over the values to create the dropdown, you're going to see each character as an item since that's how python iterates over a string.
You should be building a list instead of a string, which might look something like this:
get_sel_val = []
for p in ports:
    if (p.device) != (''):
        get_sel_val.append(p.device)
print(", ".join(get_sel_val))
my_combo = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(root, values = get_sel_val)


Thanks for your reply. I now understand a little more.
